# Is there a way to list all partitions of a set by moving one element at a time?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

Given a set $S = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, imagine that you start from an initial partition $P^{(0)} = \{P^{(0)}_1, P^{(0)}_2, \ldots\}$ of $S$, then you a create new one $P^{(1)}$ by moving only one element from a block $P^{(0)}_i$ to some other block $P^{(0)}_j$, and so on. You are also allowed to a create a new block, i.e., moves such as $\{\{1, 2, 3\}\} \rightarrow \{\{1, 2\}, \{3\}\}$ are allowed. Is it possible to list all partitions of $S$ in this way, such that no partition repeats in the list?

It's possible when $n=1,2,3$. I don't know for $n=4$. Any help is appreciated!

Illustration for $n=3$:

$$(1)(2)(3) \rightarrow (1,2)(3) \rightarrow (1)(2,3) \rightarrow (1,3)(2) \rightarrow (1, 2, 3)$$

I first moved $1$, then $2$, then $3$ and lastly $2$.

Comment: there is a book of algorithms, Nijenhuis and Wilf. Let me see if I can get a correct reference and author spelling.  https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/website/CombinatorialAlgorithms.pdf

Comment: You must mean you can create new blocks in the partition, e.g. $\{\{1, 2\}\} \to \{\{1\}, \{2\}\}$ is allowed, otherwise the number of blocks will be constant and you won't be able to get everywhere. This is your intention, correct?

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Oh, yes. You can also move an element to an empty subset as well. I forgot, thanks!

Comment: Depending on what you have in mind, the [reflected binary codes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) or Gray codes might be of interest.  Sharing your illustration for $n=3$ would help Readers understand what operations are allowed.

Comment: Can't you do some kind of induction? Single out one element. Move it through all subsets (including one step where it is on its own). Pretend it weren't there and do one step from induction hypothesis. Then start over.

Comment: @hardmath Yeah, I was thinking about enumuration by coding techniques such the ones you mentioned. There are a lot of work that lists partitions in this way, but I couldn't find a one that achieves what I want in this question. But I'm not very familiar with the literature. Let me add the illustration for $n=3$ very quick!

Comment: @loopywalt: That should be an answer!

Comment: @loopywalt How did I not think of that? Yeah, it feels so obvious now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.

Proof/construction:

Proceed by induction.

Verify directly for small sets.

Given a finite set $S$ of size $n>1$ single out an arbitrary element $s\in S$. Let $f_s$ be the map from $\mathcal P (S)$ to $\mathcal P (S - \{s\})$ obtained by leaving out $s$. Here $\mathcal P$ is the set of partitions.

Then

- $f_s$ is surjective
- the preimage $f_s^{-1}(p)$ of a partition $p \in \mathcal P (S - \{s\})$ can be traversed by moving around $s$
- if $p' \in \mathcal P (S - \{s\})$ is obtained from $p$ by moving a single element $x$ then for any element $P \in f_s^{-1}(p)$ there is a corresponding (though not necessarily unique) move of $x$ that takes $P$ into $f_s^{-1}(p')$

We can therefore "lift" a traversal T of $\mathcal P (S - \{s\})$ to a traversal of $\mathcal P (S)$ by alternating lifting single steps from T with traversing the preimage of the current partition of $S - \{s\}$. $\square$